# Android - Unable to click admob banner

Tags: android, eclipse, admob

i can see ADMOB banner but its UN-clickable, please check my XML file.

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:layout_width`enter code here`="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:background="@drawable/bg"
     tools:context=".MainActivity" >

     <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
         android:id="@+id/adView"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         ads:adSize="BANNER"
         ads:adUnitId="xxxxxxx" >
     </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

     <RelativeLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent" >

         <LinearLayout
             android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_centerInParent="true"
             android:gravity="center"
             android:orientation="horizontal" >

             <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ItemId"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/box_blank"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/new" />
         </LinearLayout>

         <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/nextId"
            android:layout_width="52dp"
            android:layout_height="52dp"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:src="@drawable/next" />

         </LinearLayout>
     </RelativeLayout>

   </RelativeLayout>
```

above file works fine for displaying just problem is not clicking the banner.

please help me with it, or any idea will help.

above file works fine for displaying just problem is not clicking the banner.

please help me with it, or any idea will help.
thanks

Comment: What about the java code? Can you upload it?

Answer (score 0):

Your ad may be covered by some of your other xml layout elements. If it is the case they would be stealing the clicks.

You can check by assigning android:background="" on you xml elements. If they overlap then that is your problem.